# Extract lang value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the lang value from the HTML tag, but the current JavaScript I am using doesn't work.

This is the HTML code I am trying to access:

```
<html  lang="it-IT">
```

And the Javascript

```
if(navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
{
    langType = navigator.language;
}
else
{
    langType = navigator.browserLanguage;
}
```

but in testing I still get the value "EN-us"

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: exact duplicated: [How to obtain lang attribute in html using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949341/1505348)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985251/1823469

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use

```
document.documentElement.lang
```

As Rob has commented, your code gets the browser's language and not the document's.

Comment: works for level2 DOM supported browsers.  level1 would need the elaborate version of nickyt.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
var language = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");
```

I haven't tried it, but it should work.

Comment: Just to clarify, the navigator object is used to access information based on the user agent accessing the page. Like nickyt mentions, you need to access the DOM to get access the attribute you are looking for, not the user agent (unless you are looking for the user's pref!) http://is.gd/o2On

Comment: I agree that document.documentElement.lang is cleaner. I just wasn't aware of this property.