# How to obtain lang attribute in HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to obtain `lang` attribute in HTML using JavaScript?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Answer (score 234, accepted):

If both attributes agree on their values (as they should), it's enough to read either of them. I'd suggest using

```
document.documentElement.lang
```

Comment: Does this fetch the `xml:lang` or the `lang` attribute?

Comment: @KrisSelbekk: should be the `lang` attribute, but I haven't done anything to verify this...

Comment: This will not work with `xml:lang` 

Ref : [Dev mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/lang)

Answer (score 33):

Just.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');
```

And with the namespace

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('xml:lang');
```