# Useful ways for multilanguage navigation and static content on your site?

Tags: php, jquery, apache, xhtml, multilingual

I have a big site running under `Apache` and `PHP` and in few mounths I should consider to add some different language version of it, but I'm not sure about the right way (or ways).

My problem it isn't the user data, because I can use db tables with different languages (en, de, it, etc.) so I want concentrate my answer on navigation and static content.

For now I can't use gettext because I don't have a dedicated server and I can't reboot it every time I want, but surely will be a future choice.

**So my main problems are these:**

In the site, I have classical `XHTML elements` like the `menus`, `lists`, `div` and `various static texts` in various pages (should be perferct for gettext, but I need a alternative)

The other part of the sites has `XHTML elements` which are `dynamically created via AJAX and jQuery`, and here I haven't any idea of what can I do...

So does exists some example I can see in some link to solve it (or some useful tecnique)?

Note:
• The user should be able to change language
• I'd like to avoid multiple divs for different languages in one page, this will be stole me too much bandwith I need, because it could be highly trafficated

Answer (score 0):

This is explicitly provided for in the XML/XHTML and CSS specs: you want to read up on the lang attribute.

```
<!-- in english -->
<div lang="en">This is written in English.</div>
<!-- in french, excuse poor french please -->
<div lang="fr">Ceci c'est ecrit en francais.</div>
<!-- in dutch -->
<div lang="nl">Dit is geschreven in het Nederlands.</div>
```

There's special syntax for CSS to apply styles depending on the lang attribute, too.

Comment: thanks for reply, does exist any kind of control on this language selection, like the possibility of language changing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? If you mean is it possible to change lang values with something like JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949341/how-to-obtain-lang-attribute-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: I asking you if I can change language like LastFM.com, so with a navigation menu which contains languages list.
I'm really confused about multilanguage because I never used it

Comment: Certainly you could: much like you can use a combination of CSS and class names in JavaScript to show/hide content you can do the same with lang attribute.

Furthermore you could inspect HTTP headers on the server to select the right default using your server-side language of choice.