# Set i18next language based on HTML tag

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

OK, so I'm experimenting with ReactJS and i18next.

I want to set my translation language on the initial page load based on
some html tag.

For example if I have `<html lang="de">` when the page is loaded I would like to have
the `lng` set to `de` before any translations take place.

Here's the content of my `i18n.js` file:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

// the translations
// (tip move them in a JSON file and import them)
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      "Welcome to React": "Translation in English"
    }
  },
  de: {
    translation: {
      "Welcome to React": "Translation in German"
    }
  }
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en",

    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

  export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949341/how-to-obtain-lang-attribute-in-html-using-javascript)

```
const htmlLang = document.documentElement.lang; // for <html lang=".."> not xml-lang:".."
```

Now you can put this constant in youe i18n declaration

```
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: htmlLang,

    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    },
    fallbackLng: ['en', //'fr', ...]
  });
```

I also add a fallback language